# Remove JavaScript with sed

Tags: javascript, html, sed

Im getting a lot pain because this code is not working. I try to extract all the html tags and javascript tags and content of the javascript from a html file and get the clear content.

```
sed  -e 's/<[^>]\+>/ /g' -e '/<script/,/<\/script>/d'
```

This code removes the html tags and the script tag but does not remove the script content.

```
sed  -e 's/<[^>]\+>/ /g' -e 's/<script>try.*<\/script>//'
```

This should work for more script tags trought the document but still does not remove the content.
However this code is removing the script AND the content within but I just cant seem to make it work togheter with the html removal.

```
awk '/<script>/{p=1} /<\/script>/{p=0;next}!p'
```

So when i combine it and make something like this next code it does removes the script and the content but the HTML tags stay

```
sed 's/<[^>]\+>/ /g' | awk '/<script>/{p=1} /<\/script>/{p=0;next}!p'
```

example data:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>BTKRSH //</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head>
<script>
    //test test 
</script>
<body>
    <div class="left">
        <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            <div id="closebtn">
                <a class="hidden-x">    <img src="x-gray.png"></img> </a>
            </div>
            <tr><td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">
                <div class="menu">
                    <a>PODCASTS</a>
                    <div class="hidden-menu podcasts">
                        <iframe width="400" height="400" src="https://www.mixcloud.com/widget/iframe/?feed=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mixcloud.com%2FBTKRSH%2F&amp;embed_uuid=f78341ae-da15-480f-9604-d6812bb9a83d&amp;replace=0&amp;stylecolor=190303&amp;embed_type=widget_standard" frameborder="0"></iframe><div style="clear: both; height: 3px; width: 392px;"></div><p style="display: block; font-size: 11px; font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0px; padding: 3px 4px; color: rgb(153, 153, 153); width: 392px;"><a href="http://www.mixcloud.com/BTKRSH/?utm_source=widget&amp;amp;utm_medium=web&amp;amp;utm_campaign=base_links&amp;amp;utm_term=resource_link" target="_blank" style="color: rgb(25, 3, 3); font-weight: bold;">
                    </div>
                    <a>RELEASES</a>
                    <div class="hidden-menu releases">

                    </div>
                    <a>ARTISTS</a>
                    <div class="hidden-menu artists">

                    </div>
                    <a>LINKS</a>
                    <div class="hidden-menu links">

                    </div>
                    <a>ABOUT</a>
                    <div class="hidden-menu about">

                    </div>
                    <a>CONTACT</a>
                    <div class="hidden-menu contact">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </td></tr>

        </table>

    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <table style="width:100%; height: 100%;">
            <tr><td style="vertucal-align: middle; text-align: center">
                <img src="2001_7.jpg" class="btkrsh-mask" width="600" height="500" ></img>
                    <div id="graph-art">
                    <p>BACKGROUND ARTIST</p>
                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/btkrsh">SIMON C PAIGE<a>
                </div>
            <td></tr>
        </table>


    </div>

</body>
```

RESULTS:

BTKRSH //

```
            //test test









                                             PODCASTS



                                             RELEASES



                                             ARTISTS



                                             LINKS



                                             ABOUT



                                             CONTACT















                                             BACKGROUND ARTIST
                                             SIMON C PAIGE
```

Or when i use the code that DELETES the script tags and content i get this:

```
<html>
    <head>
            <title>BTKRSH //</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
            <div class="left">
                    <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                            <div id="closebtn">
                                    <a class="hidden-x">    <img src="x-gray.png"></img> </a>
                            </div>
                            <tr><td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">
                                    <div class="menu">
                                            <a>PODCASTS</a>
                                            <div class="hidden-menu podcasts">
                                                    <iframe width="400" height="400" src="https://www.mixcloud.com/widget/iframe/?feed=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mixcloud.com%2FBTKRSH%2F&amp;embed_uuid=f78341ae-da15-480f-9604-d6812bb9a83d&amp;replace=0&amp;stylecolor=190303&amp;embed_type=widget_standard" frameborder="0"></iframe><div style="clear: both; height: 3px; width: 392px;"></div><p style="display: block; font-size: 11px; font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0px; padding: 3px 4px; color: rgb(153, 153, 153); width: 392px;"><a href="http://www.mixcloud.com/BTKRSH/?utm_source=widget&amp;amp;utm_medium=web&amp;amp;utm_campaign=base_links&amp;amp;utm_term=resource_link" target="_blank" style="color: rgb(25, 3, 3); font-weight: bold;">
                                            </div>
                                            <a>RELEASES</a>
                                            <div class="hidden-menu releases">

                                            </div>
                                            <a>ARTISTS</a>
                                            <div class="hidden-menu artists">

                                            </div>
                                            <a>LINKS</a>
                                            <div class="hidden-menu links">

                                            </div>
                                            <a>ABOUT</a>
                                            <div class="hidden-menu about">

                                            </div>
                                            <a>CONTACT</a>
                                            <div class="hidden-menu contact">

                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                            </td></tr>

                    </table>

            </div>

            <div class="right">
                    <table style="width:100%; height: 100%;">
                            <tr><td style="vertucal-align: middle; text-align: center">
                                    <img src="2001_7.jpg" class="btkrsh-mask" width="600" height="500" ></img>
                                            <div id="graph-art">
                                            <p>BACKGROUND ARTIST</p>
                                            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/btkrsh">SIMON C PAIGE<a>
                                    </div>
                            <td></tr>
                    </table>


            </div>

    </body>
```

You see the script tag and content is gone here

Any help is welcome, Thanks!

Comment: Example data would help.

Comment: @Jotne well the html file is too large to upload it here, the thing is it should work with every html file you load, and it does as stated

Comment: Don't do this. Just don't. Use something that claims to actually meaningfully parse "html". There's a reason tools for this exist. It isn't simple or straighforward if you want to handle even remotely complicated real-life examples of "html" that people and tools have written over the years. Try something like `elinks -dump` or any of the various perl/python/ruby modules.

Comment: @Jotne i uploaded example and results

Comment: @EtanReisner yes, but I have to do it with sed or awk.

Comment: Then may $DIETY have mercy on your soul and bless you with only well-formed input.

Comment: @EtanReisner you say it can't be done?

Comment: For arbitrary input? Quite likely not. For limited, well-formed (or at least only known broken) input? Probably (though how easily is a different question). "html", despite the spec, is a horrible mess in the real world. Browsers historically have been **very** lenient when it comes to parsing. Much of the HTML5 working group's work, in fact, was standardizing on which lenient parsing behaviors were going to be allowed and made canonical, etc.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks! I'll give it a few more tries though:)

Comment: Really don't. People have done this work for you, correctly. Just use their stuff. Save yourself time and hassle and broken-ness down the line when your input changes. But suit yourself.